# msvcr* spec file for mingw-w64

Tags: windows, mingw, mingw-w64

[This HOWTO](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_the_GCC_specs_file) describes how to modify the default GCC spec file for MinGW so that a small secondary spec file can specify the msvcrt version to use.

When applying the same technique I ran into two issues:

1. MinGW-w64 doesn't have any libmoldname*.a (where * is 80, 90, 100, 110 etc) matching the libmsvcr*.a versions. Are these missing or just not necessary?
2. The -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x*0 defined via the msvcrt_version does not take effect. The spec file *is* used, because dumpbin tells me that I am now linking to a different msvcrt version, the define however does not work. If I define it directly via the command line it does, but that misses the point of the spec file. Is there any way to fix this?

For completeness' sake here are the relevant lines in the default spec file:

```
*cpp:
%(msvcrt_version) %{posix:-D_POSIX_SOURCE} %{mthreads:-D_MT} %{municode:-DUNICODE} %{!no-pthread:-D_REENTRANT} %{pthread:-U_REENTRANT}

*libgcc:
%{mthreads:-lmingwthrd} -lmingw32      %{static|static-libgcc:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}  %{!static:    %{!static-libgcc:      %{!shared:        %{!shared-libgcc:-lgcc -lgcc_eh}        %{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s -lgcc}       }      %{shared:-lgcc_s -lgcc}     }   }     -l%(moldname) -lmingwex -l%(msvcrt)

*msvcrt:
msvcrt

*msvcrt_version:


*moldname:
moldname
```

And the content of my msvcr110 spec file (with moldname110 already replaced by moldname due to issue 1):

```
*msvcrt:
msvcr110

*msvcrt_version:
-D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1100

*moldname:
moldname
```

**EDIT:**

Adding `%(msvcrt_version)` to and `*cc1` and `*cc1plus` instead of to `*cpp` appears to solve the issue of the missing define.

Comment: The "old names" just get a older, they don't change.  The mingw version, libmoldname.a is empty so it just doesn't matter.  The #define for the MSVC version is for *your* benefit, mingw doesn't use it at all.  Pretty unlikely you'll have a use for it.

Comment: @HansPassant the define is set to 0x700 by default, if not provided by the command line. And some functions just don't exist in the older msvcrt. So I do definitely need it to know which functions I can use.

Comment: Well, use it then.  What is the real problem here?  What *exactly* goes wrong?  Post a snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant the original question (more specifically point 2) already states the problem... Posting a code snippet which prints the value of __MSVCRT_VERSION__ is really not useful...

Comment: @HansPassant Where is spec file located in mingw-w64?